# Fetching multiple rows returns Undefined Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to code a warning system for a discord bot using Discord.JS and Sequelize. Saving the warns works, but fetching doesn't work.

```js
async function warnGet() {
            let msgArgs = message.content.split(" ");
            var ReportID = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
            let messageReason = msgArgs[2]
              ? message.content.substring(
                  msgArgs.slice(0, 3).join(" ").length + 1
                )
              : "No reason provided";
            (async () => {
              try {
                let userTag = member.user.tag;
                let warningYes = JSON.stringify(
                  await moderationLogging.findAll({
                    where: {
                      Member: userTag,
                    },
                  }),
                  { raw: true }
                );
                warningYes = JSON.parse(warningYes);
                const faqembed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setColor("#ff9100")
                  .addField(
                    `Reason: ${warningYes.Reason}`,
                    `Report ID: ${warningYes.ReprtID}`
                  )
                  .setAuthor(
                    member.user.username,
                    member.user.displayAvatarURL({
                      format: "jpg",
                      dynamic: "true",
                    })
                  );
                warningYes.forEach((e) => {
                  faqembed.addField(
                    `Reason: ${warningYes.Reason}`,
                    `Report ID: ${warningYes.ReprtID}`
                  );
                });
                message.channel.send(faqembed);
              } catch (error) {
                message.channel.send(
                  `Aw maaaaan. I couldn't do the thing I needed to do. <@388813100964642816> should prob know about this. The technical stuff\` \`\`\`xl\n${clean(
                    error
                  )}\n\`\`\``
                );
                console.log(error);
              }
            })();
          }
```

this code when ran returns this
[This leads to the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v500R.png)

I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.
These are the entries it's trying to get [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MmiF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update! So, I actually solved it on my own! Instead of doing

```js
               warningYes = JSON.parse(warningYes);
                const faqembed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setColor("#ff9100")
                  .addField(
                    `Reason: ${warningYes.Reason}`,
                    `Report ID: ${warningYes.ReprtID}`
                  )
```

I did this

```js
                const warning = JSON.parse(warningYes);
                const faqembed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setColor("#ff9100")
                  .addField(
                    `Reason: ${warning[0].Reason}`,
                    `Report ID: ${warning[0].ReprtID}`
                  )
                  .setAuthor(
                    member.user.username,
                    member.user.displayAvatarURL({
                      format: "jpg",
                      dynamic: "true",
                    })
                  );
```

If you need to know, I added a [0] on the end of it. Turns out that was all I needed. It's fixed now, so yeah!